# How to unzip files that are in individual folders?

Tags: file, terminal, zip, unzip, directory

I own a MacBook Air. I'm trying to unzip all of these folders all at once instead of double clicking on each zip file that are in each directory. Is it possible? If so, how? For example, Folder 1 contains Cow.zip and Pig.zip, Folder 2 contains Dragon.zip, Dog.zip, and Cat.zip and 
Folder 3 contains Hen.zip and Flowers.zip. Folder 1, Folder 2, and Folder 3, are in File called Animals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open ./*/*.zip
```

This will recursively traverse all the folders in the current directory and `open` all .zip files (i.e. "double click"/unzip).

If you need to unzip lots of files, use this command instead to avoid numerous pop ups. (Replace `path/to/folder` with the path that contains the folders with zips/more folders)

```
find path/to/folder -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do unzip -o -d "`dirname "$filename"`" "$filename"; done;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to do it with 37 files that contain 22 files each that also contains .zip files? I keep getting numerous pop ups. What command will this be?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that. I edited my original answer.

Comment: I tried doing the command:  cd Desktop/AB -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do unzip -o -d "`dirname "$filename"`" "$filename"; done;

Comment: But it didn't work. Oh I should specify! File A contains 37 files that contains 22 files each that also contains .zip files.